# SQL Query to SUM(*) for each day of this week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an app that enables users to scan a logo and win "points". They can scan more than once per day.  I'm trying to write a query that returns the total points for each day of this week.  Thus far, I'm able to return all records for each day of the week.  The challenge is how to sum total points for each day.  Here is what I have thus far:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1 -- Beginning of week is Monday
SELECT ScanID, UserID, DateTime, BeerID, BrewerID, Points 
FROM SmartTappScanLog
WHERE DateTime >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) 
  AND DateTime <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate()))
  AND UserID = '1' AND BeerID = '3'
  ORDER BY DateTime ASC
```

So if there are two scans Monday worth 2 and 5 Points, I want to return 7 for Monday.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an aggregation.  Something like this will get one row per day in the data:

```
SELECT CAST(Datetime as date) as date, UserID, BeerID, SUM(Points) as points
FROM SmartTappScanLog
WHERE DateTime >= dateadd(day, 1-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) AND
      DateTime <  dateadd(day, 8-datepart(dw, getdate()), CONVERT(date,getdate())) AND
      UserID = 1 AND BeerID = 3
GROUP BY CAST(Datetime as date), UserID, BeerID
ORDER BY MIN(DateTime) ASC;
```

If you want the day of the week in the output, use `datepart()` or `datename()` to get it.

Comment: This is excellent!  The only thing I had to do was add AS Date, and AS Points to add these column names.  Thank you so much!! Can't accept your answer for 6 minutes.